# Building the Sparse Bundle Adjustment (SBA) library on OS X

Tags: osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build `slam_karto` from source, which in turn needs `open_karto` and `sparse_bundle_adjustment`

The [sparse_bundle_adjustment](https://github.com/ros-perception/sparse_bundle_adjustment) catkin package has 3 dependencies of interest: `liblapack-dev`, `libblas-dev`, and `suitesparse` OS X comes with (some version of) the first two.

I then tried three different ways of installing SuiteSparse:

- This catkin wrapper: https://github.com/ethz-asl/suitesparse It seemed to work. But then when I tried to build SBA the linker complained that `ld: library not found for -lcholmod`
- Installing SuiteSparse from source http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html Got lost in dependencies.
  `clang: error: no such file or directory: '[...]/SuiteSparse/lib/libmetis.dylib'`
- Realizing it's available via Homebrew, `brew install suite-sparse` This got me `metis`, the dependency above, and installed SuiteSparse. But then, when I tried to compile SBA: `fatal error: 'suitesparse/cs.h' file not found` I commented out that `#include "suitesparse/cs.h"` just to see if it can find other headers. It cannot: `fatal error: 'suitesparse/cholmod.h' file not found` However, these headers are indeed under: `/usr/local/Cellar/suite-sparse/4.5.1/include` and the seem to be symlinked from`/usr/loca/include`, e.g., `cs.h -> ../Cellar/suite-sparse/4.5.1/include/cs.h`

Has anyone been able to build SBA (and SLAM Karto in general) on OS X? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232103/building-the-sparse-bundle-adjustment-(sba)-library-on-os-x/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized that the Homebrew formula placed the header files directly under `/usr/local/Cellar/suite-sparse/4.5.1/include`. That is, there is no `/usr/local/Cellar/suite-sparse/4.5.1/include/suitesparse` directory. (By contrast, in Ubuntu the headers are placed under `/usr/include/suitesparse`)

Therefore, by changing the include directives in SBA, specifically in `csparse.h`, to `#include "cs.h"` and `#include "cholmod.h"`, I was able to compile the `sparse_bundle_adjustment` package.

Alternatively, it also works if I create the following symlink myself and keep SBA untouched:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/suite-sparse/4.5.1/include /usr/local/include/suitesparse
```

PS. I was able to build `slam_karto` too afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0